# Search result page leading to a specific page [up]

Tags: php, html, search

I am creating a database website wherein there is a search bar then it will lead to a search results page (in table form). The user will then select a specific result that would lead to a custom webpage for that result. Is there a way to do that in PHP/MYSQL?

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
include "databaseconnect.php";

$keywordfromform = $_GET["Search"];

$sql = ("SELECT titleID, authorsID, yearID, subjectID 
        FROM researchpapertable 
        WHERE titleID LIKE '%" . $keywordfromform . "%'
        OR authorsID LIKE '%" . $keywordfromform . "%'
        OR yearID LIKE '%" . $keywordfromform . "%'
        OR subjectID LIKE '%" . $keywordfromform . "%'
        ");
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result-> num_rows>0) {
  // output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr><td><a href="indivpage.php">'. $row["titleID"]."</a></td><td>". $row["authorsID"]."</td><td>". $row["yearID"]."</td><td>". $row["subjectID"]."</td></tr>";
  }

} else {
  echo "<tr><td> 0 results </td><td> 0 results </td><td> 0 results </td><td> 0 results </td><tr>";
}

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

I placed a `<a href="indivpage.php">` in the column where they will select the title of their choice. What should I place there for it to lead to its specific page? I am not sure what I should search for in order to search for similar tutorials/code. If there are similar questions/code to this, it would help a lot. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the difference between indivpage.php and indiv.php ?

Comment: @Max Muster it's basically the same, I edited it already to avoid confusion. I would just like to point out that indivpage.php is basically the page that will lead to the custom page that they select.

Comment: To create a hyperlink in HTML you need  <a> tag

Comment: you want to transport the variables `$row["titleID"], $row["authorsID"],  $row["yearID"],  $row["subjectID"]` and so on to this indivpage.php ? Somthing like : `<a href="http://example.com/indivpage.php?titleID=$row["titleID"]...</a>` etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would send a unique identifier as a parameter to your page. Like this:

```
echo '<tr><td><a href="indivpage.php?title_id=' . $row[titleID'] . '">' . $row["titleID"] . '</a>...etc...</td></tr>';
```

Then in your indivpage.php you would use `$_GET['title_id']` to fetch all the details from the database.

Let me add to this that there is very much wrong with the code you wrote. To begin with I would suggest to [read about SQL injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)